# How to remove addtoany js for a particular node page?

Tags: 8, javascript

I need to unset addtoany module js for a particular node.

For that I have implemented

```
 function theme_name_js_alter(&$javascript) {
    if(\Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage()) {
            unset($javascript['https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js']);
            unset($javascript['modules/contrib/addtoany/js/addtoany.js']);
            unset($javascript['themes/test/js/index.js']);
            unset($javascript['themes/test/js/custom.js']);
        }
    }
```

Above code unset *index.js* & *custom.js* but not works for *addtoany.js* and *page.js*.

Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Double check the asset URLs?

Comment: addtoany library is added using hook_page_attachments(), did you ensure your hook_js_alter() is called after that one? Perhaps you could give a try to hook_page_attachments_alter() or try removing the addtoany/addtoany library instead of the files.

Comment: Thanks @misterdidi. Your comment help to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implements **hook_page_attachments_alter()** to resolve it.

```
function theme_name_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments['#attached']['library'] as $key => $library) {
        if ($library == 'addtoany/addtoany') {
          unset($attachments['#attached']['library'][$key]);
        }
    }
}
```